# How to compare two comma-separated value in a column, and return only matching values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with comma-separated strings, I need to compare it with another comma-separated column and return only matching values.

For example

```
column 1 = John, james, steve
column 2 = john, smith, will, james
```

I need a result like `John,james` since it is available in both column 1 and column 2. Is this possible in SQL?

As I'm using SQL Server 2012, I'm not able to use the `String_split` function

Comment: see [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and tell us why you did not work out an example with this function, and where you failed to come to a solution.

Comment: The problem with designing your database tables poorly is that it makes them extremely difficult to work with when you need to query that data. Your better solution would be to grab a book on basic SQL and database design, and properly structure your data so you don't have these sorts of issues.

Comment: Version compatibility - as i use SQL 2012 and compatibility level is 110

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution.

It is using XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 VARCHAR(MAX), col2 VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (col1, col2) VALUES
('John, james, steve', 'john, smith, will, james'),
('Mary, Lisa', 'Mary');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = ', ';

SELECT * 
    , REPLACE(TRY_CAST('<root>' + 
    '<source><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(col1, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></source>' + 
    '<target><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(col2, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></target>' + 
    '</root>' AS XML)
    .query('
    for $x in /root/source/r/text(),
        $y in /root/target/r/text()
    where lower-case($y) eq lower-case($x)
    return data($x)
    ').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), ',')  AS result
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+------------+
| ID |        col1        |           col2           |   result   |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+------------+
|  1 | John, james, steve | john, smith, will, james | John,james |
|  2 | Mary, Lisa         | Mary                     | Mary       |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Khabinsky . This solution solves my query. it works as expected

Comment: @user15795435, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be done using `STRING_SPLIT()`:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(MAX) = 'john,james,steve'
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(MAX) = 'john,smith,will,james'

SELECT a.value
FROM string_split(@a, ',') a
JOIN string_split(@b, ',') b
    ON a.value = b.value
```

But I think the broader question is if you should be doing this in SQL at all. SQL is much better and more efficient at set-based operations, and this approach is very iterative going row by row. I would consider restructing your data so it's easier to do this or read it into memory and use C# to do this type of manipulation.

Comment: OP mentioned 2012

Comment: As I use SQL 2012 , I am having compatibility issue using string_split

Comment: You accomplish the string_split functionality using XML, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/, but this is a hacky workaround and another indicator that you should redesign your data model or do this in memory. SQL isn't really designed for this type of operation and it won't be performant.

Comment: Thanks pwang. I will try redesigning the model